# Is it possible to add a loop inside WordPress content?

Tags: wordpress, loops

I would like to include, into certain WordPress posts or pages, mini-loops such as "the latest X articles on this topic". That would mean adding a loop inside the_content() (a loop inside the loop). Is there any way to do that, without appending said mini-loop above or below the_content()? Calling it right from the text editor? If so, how?

Comment: As this is a site for programmers, and this isn't really a programming question, I am voting to close.  Note that the ONLY way to do something like this from within the editor is to either write, or install, a shortcode that creates a "latest X posts".  I'm confident a quick google search for "wordpress latest posts shortcode" will turn up plenty of results.

Comment: This is a programming question - as the poster mentions `the_content()` which would lead to the assumption OP understands how the template works. OP, as @cale_b suggested, I would strongly consider building your own shortcode function that does this. So you can write the content in the WYSIWYG but include shortcode. I'm sure there are plugins that do this already, but it's fairly simple to do it yourself. I will say, in agreement with @cale_b though, that you should probably try something before posting the question here.

Comment: Thanks @disinfor. I've been hectically searching yesterday "loop inside the content" (and all the variables) and came up with nothing. You are correct: I want to be able to add my own code in various places (and select which category, for example, and how many posts) so a plugin wouldn't cut it. I am worried that inserting a loop inside the_content() may just break the original loop, and wouldn't want to waste hours trying to develop if that's not possible. I am a beginner, but still, I am developing. I didn't even think of shortcode, actually. I will explore this.

Comment: @Corinne WordPress offers a way to create a loop within the loop - otherwise there are tons of things we wouldn't be able to do as developers in WP. Search for creating a custom WP Query, `wp_reset_postdata` and shortcode creation. The WP codex is a great resource for examples and help.